# Unable to cast anonymous list into known list in LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a LINQ Query which returns me results from one table. I need to convert it into the List of that table model. The anonymous type of groupManager is List<`a> where`a is {Group g5}

```
var groups = new List<Group>();
var groupManager = (from a in db.AUsers
                                join b in db.BUsers on a.Id equals b.UserID into group1
                                from g1 in group1.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                join c in db.UserRoles on g1.ID equals c.UserID into group2
                                from g2 in group2.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                join d in db.Roles on g2.RoleID equals d.ID into group3
                                from g3 in group3.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                join e in db.RoleGroups on g3.ID equals e.RoleID into group4
                                from g4 in group4.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                join f in db.Groups on g4.GroupID equals f.ID into group5
                                from g5 in group5.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                where a.Id == user.ID && g5.Name != ""
                                select new{ Group = g5}).ToList();

groups = groupManager.Cast<Group>().ToList();
```

This code does not seem to work.The error I am getting is {"Unable to cast object of type '<>f__AnonymousType11`1[Group]' to type 'Group'."} Am I missing something?

Comment: Why are you wrapping the value in an anonymous object in the first place, if you just want the value itself?

Comment: groupManager is of type List<Group>()
why do you even try to cast it?

Comment: @Servy What do you think I should be doing?

Comment: @The_Outsider If you don't need the value wrapped in an anonymous object, don't wrap it in an anonymous object.  You're going out of your way to turn your group into an anonymous object that has a group in it, and then asking how to turn that anonymous object into a group.

Comment: @The_Outsider - I give two ways to not wrap in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

hmmm... did you try this?

```
 select new Group(g5)).ToList();
```

or this

```
 select g5).ToList();
```

hard to say more without knowing anything about the group object or the other types in your example.

Comment: Does not work becasue my Group constructor does not take parameters.Trying out the second one, let me check

Comment: @The_Outsider - then write a constructor that does or use the 2nd example.

Answer (score 0):

You can likely do this without the anonymous type or the cast.

```
var groups = (from a in db.AUsers
              // Your query...
              select new Group
              {
                  // Properties of Group
                  Name = g5.Name,
                  AnotherProperty = g5.AnotherProperty
              }).ToList();
```

Comment: Lots of columns in the table, surely there should be an easier way

Comment: Is your table an EntitySet<Group>? If so simply select g5 as suggested by Hogan. I was assuming this was not the case as I thought you would have gotten there on your own.

Answer (score 0):

Provided answers were absolutely correct, but I guess it could be good to point one subtle thing out regarding `Cast` method (and to answer "Am I missing something" part).

`Cast` method really serves different purpose than casting all objects in list to another type. No surprise that compiler throws this exception since what `Cast` does is taking `IEnumerable` (non generic version) and returning the same collection, but with generic `IEnumerable<T>`. This is one of two methods in LINQ that are taking non generic `IEnumerable` as an argument (the second is `OfType`), so you could have a collection of given type, cast it to `IEnumerable<T>` and use other LINQ methods which require `IEnumerable<T>` as an argument.

Just look at the source code

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Cast<TResult>(this IEnumerable source) {
    IEnumerable<TResult> typedSource = source as IEnumerable<TResult>;
    if (typedSource != null) return typedSource;
    if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    return CastIterator<TResult>(source);
}
```

and in `CastIterator`

```
foreach (object obj in source) yield return (TResult)obj;
```

so your collection should be able to be casted to given type `T` in order to `Cast` to work. It won't cast your anonymous types to concrete types.

Comment: Wow that is going deep.   I like it.

Answer (score 0):

If you select the actual object then that's what you get back as an IEnumerable of Group:

```
var groups = new List<Group>();
var groupManager = (from a in db.AUsers
                            join b in db.BUsers on a.Id equals b.UserID into group1
                            from g1 in group1.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            join c in db.UserRoles on g1.ID equals c.UserID into group2
                            from g2 in group2.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            join d in db.Roles on g2.RoleID equals d.ID into group3
                            from g3 in group3.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            join e in db.RoleGroups on g3.ID equals e.RoleID into group4
                            from g4 in group4.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            join f in db.Groups on g4.GroupID equals f.ID into group5
                            from g5 in group5.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            where a.Id == user.ID && g5.Name != ""
                            select g5).ToList()
groups = groupManager;
```

The .ToList() will then convert it to a list.  No need to create a dynamic object and then cast.